# Updating existing record for duplicate entry and inserting records for a new entry in INFLUX DB (Similar to ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, influxdb

I have a MySQL table where I update the existing records when there is a duplicate value and insert a new record when there is a new entry on some of the columns using '**ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**'.

```
INSERT INTO TestDB 
                (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4) 
            VALUES 
                (val_1, val_2, val_3, val_4)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                col_2 = VALUES(col_2),
                col_3 = VALUES(col_3)
```

Now, I need the exact case with influxdb also. But I can't find anything that will do the same with influx.

Influx measurement will be something like this

```
INSERT TestDB,col_1=val_1,col_2=val_2,col_3=val_3 col_4="val_4"
```

In the current scenario with Influx DB, when I insert a duplicate record, it inserts a new record with obviously a new timestamp, but what I require is, to update the first record if it tries to insert a duplicate value (with new timestamp) and insert a new record only if val_2 and val_3 changes.

So, is there an 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' equivalent in Influx DB to achieve the same result?

NB: I'm using using the influx command line in my local machine and the admin page (with 8083 port) to insert and query the measurements.

Comment: Unfortunately, this functionality doesn't exist in InfluxDB yet. Please open a [feature request](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/new).

Comment: Some info on this: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/2575#issuecomment-102071093

Answer (score 3):

InfluxDB updates the same record if all the tags(including time) in the record to be inserted into influx are duplicate no matter whether fields are different or not.

i.e., influx maintains the unique tags combination key